# acessar um objeto json como se este fosse um array

Tags: javascript, node.js

Preciso acessar um objeto json como se este fosse um array, Exemplo
Tenho o seguinte objeto no lado cliente:

```
´    remessa : function (){
    var arr2 = [{
    'NrSequenciaDoc' :   '7777',  
    'TipoOcorrencia' :    '1',   
    'NossoNumero' : '66688', 
    'NumeroDocumento' : '6987',
    'DataVencimento' : '30082017', 
    'SacadoUF' : 'UF', },
    {
    'NrSequenciaDoc' :   '7777',  
    'TipoOcorrencia' :    '1',   
    'NossoNumero' : '66690', 
    'NumeroDocumento' : '6987',
    'DataVencimento' : '30082017', 
    'SacadoUF' : 'UF', }];


  axios({



    method: 'post',
    url: '/server/remessa',
    params: {
      Nrbanco : '085',
      TipoInscricao : '1',
      IncricaoCedente : '06624079975',
    ...
      Detalhe : arr2
    ...
      ,


    }

  }).then(function (response)
  {
    console.log('response.data' + response.data)
  }).catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error)
  })

}
```

e no server e tenho   `var arr = req.query.Detalhe;

for(i in arr){
    console.log(arr[i].NossoNumero);
}`

Não está funcionando, aparece undefined no console;

Comment: Esse JSON é inválido(OU OBJETO)

Comment: Não teria que trocar o `arr[i]` por `detalhe[i]`?

Comment: o var arr recebe o detahe antes do loop     var arr = req.query.Detalhe;

Comment: Você quer fazer um loop dentro de cada bloco do JSON como se cada bloco fosse um Array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o for..in (como está fazendo) , só tem de checar o hasOwnProperty, para eliminar propriedades adicionadas ao prototype. Verifique também se o JSON recebido no server é válido.

```
var object = {a:"1", b:"2", c:"3" }


for (var property in object) {
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        console.log(property
    }
}
```

Ou iterar sobre as keys das propriedades e usálas para acessar as propriedades:

```
Object.keys(object).map(function(key) {
    console.log(key, object[key])
});
```

> Baseado em : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties

Comment: Dessa maneira só terei acesso ao valor {1,2 e 3}, mas preciso das propiedades também {a,b,c}. pois terei algo nesse sentido NossoNumero = arr[i].NossoNumero

Comment: Se entendi direito a sua dúvida, A variável key terá o nome da propriedade(a, b, c). se você fizer console.log(key) terá a propriedade, e console.log(object[key]), terá o valor dela.

Answer (score 1):

Eu arrumei manualmente o seu Objeto('DataVencimento' : '30082017' tinha uma aspas simples e acabou dando problema), verifique se ele está vindo assim mesmo do server-side, de qualquer forma, para iterar sobre um objeto use `for(i in arr){` sendo `arr` o seu objeto e `i` o index.

```js
var arr = [{
'NrSequenciaDoc' :   '7777',  
'TipoOcorrencia' :    '1',   
'NossoNumero' : '66688', 
'NumeroDocumento' : '6987',
'DataVencimento' : '30082017', 
'SacadoUF' : 'UF', },
{
'NrSequenciaDoc' :   '7777',  
'TipoOcorrencia' :    '1',   
'NossoNumero' : '66690', 
'NumeroDocumento' : '6987',
'DataVencimento' : '30082017', 
'SacadoUF' : 'UF', }];

for(i in arr){
console.log(arr[i].NossoNumero);
}
```

Comment: se executo esse código direto no server node, funciona, porém se mando o mesmo objeto do front tenho não funciona, no console aparece "undefined"
e se dou um console.log(req.query.Detalhe) para verificar o objeto ele vem da seguinte forma [ '{"NrSequenciaDoc":"7777","TipoOcorrencia":"1","NossoNumero":"66688","NumeroDocumento":"6987","DataVencimento":"30082017","SacadoUF":"UF"}',
  '{"NrSequenciaDoc":"7777","TipoOcorrencia":"1","NossoNumero":"66690","NumeroDocumento":"6987","DataVencimento":"30082017","SacadoUF":"UF"}' ]

Comment: Você está processando isso no JS ou no BACK-END(server-side)?

Comment: no Js envio a requisição   e no server  executo  o loop, no front end utilizo o vue.js e axios para fazer a requisição

Comment: o que preciso é mandar esse objeto através de uma requisição http e no server fazer o lop nesse objeto

Comment: Mas o loop você quer fazer em que linguagem??

Comment: O loop será feito utilizando a linguagem do Node.js

Answer (score 0):

Funcionou da seguinta maneira :
FrontEnd o objeto ficou assim:

```
    var dadosbanco = '{"banco":[' +
    '{"NrSequenciaDoc":"7777","TipoOcorrencia":"1" ,"NossoNumero" : "66688", "NumeroDocumento" :"6987", "DataVencimento" : "30082017" },' +
    '{"NrSequenciaDoc":"7773","TipoOcorrencia":"2" ,"NossoNumero" : "66690", "NumeroDocumento" :"69898", "DataVencimento" : "30082019"  }' +
    ']}';
```

backend:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(req.query.Detalhe);
for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.banco.length; i++) {
    var counter = jsonData.banco[i];
    //console.log(counter.counter_name);
    console.log(counter.NrSequenciaDoc);
}
```

Grata pela Ajuda